# Unable to join channel on jetson nano HLF2.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, channel, nvidia-jetson-nano

Im trying to setup a network on Jetson Nano and VM on my laptop.

My version of fabric is 2.3.0.

While joining channel I have two errors

```
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to
localhost:9051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error
while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9051: connect: connection refused"
```

and the same one for 10051 port.

And then I cannot deploy chaincode with same errors and false approval from Org2MSP (Nano)

Im following this tutorial but with updated images and binaries (and rebuild arm binaries for Nano):
[Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 on Multiple Hosts](https://medium.com/@sreeananthakannan/hyperledger-fabric-2-0-on-multiple-hosts-9c10bbb22eea)

Can someone help me to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting above error because of you are running the **peer join** command from PC-1 and peers of org2 is running on PC-2 and you have exported the environment variable for **CORE_PEER_ADDRESS** as localhost:9051.

better you should run the crate and join channel commands form **cli container**.

and set the **CORE_PEER_ADDRESS**  as **container_name:port** in place of using **localhost:port**

for example if you are using join command for peer 0 of org1 then set the **CORE_PEER_ADDRESS** as following

```
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

but before this make sure your all containers are connected through docker swarm network.